# element.getText() method is not working in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<span class="label label-danger" style="font-size : 13px; font-weight : 400;">Critical</span>
```

Below is the xpath which I am using:

```
.//tr[@data-index='0']/td/span
```

I have a line in HTML source like above. So, I have used corresponding Xpath and used `getText()` method to get the text i.e. Critical. I am succeed in that.

But, I have another line in another page like this.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="project-update-success-information" class="panel-confirmation success" style="display: none;">
<span class="fa fa-check"/>
  Project Updated
</div>
```

Below is the xpath which I am using:-

```
.//*[@id='project-update-success-information']/span
```

I have used the corresponding Xpath and `getText()`,but unfortunately it doesn't retrieve the text for me. I doubted that there is no `</span>` close tag in the second line which causes the problem. Is there any other way to get the text?

Comment: Can you show us the xpath used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has many answers already, but none of them really explains the problem. First, let us get your initial confusion about self-closing elements out of the way, before moving on to the real problem: No, it is not a problem that an element like

```
<span class="fa fa-check"/>
```

does not have a `</span>` tag. There is no need to indicate where it ends because the `/>` already tells you that this element does not contain anything and closes at this point.

---

Then let's look at only the fragment of the document that you show:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <div id="project-update-success-information" class="panel-confirmation success" style="display: none;">
  <span class="fa fa-check"/>
  Project Updated
 </div>
</div>
```

An XPath expression like (note that most likely you do not need the `.` at the very beginning of the expression):

```
//*[@id='project-update-success-information']
```

will return the inner `div` element with all that it contains. What it does contain is, exactly in this order:

- a whitespace-only text node
- a self-closing `span` element with no content other than an attribute
- the text node that contains "Project Updated"

So, it is not at all surprising that when you select the inner `div` and use `.getText()`, you end up with **2** text nodes in the result. Another way to get at the text content of an element is by using `text()` in the XPath expression:

```
//*[@id='project-update-success-information']/text()
```

which will return (individual elements separated by `--------`):

```
[whitespace-only text node]
-----------------------
Project Updated
```

The solutions are either

1. use `getText()` to retrieve all text nodes and later exclude those that only contain whitespace or
2. use an XPath expression that targets text nodes directly and excludes the ones that only contain whitespace. The standard way of doing this is with `[normalize-space()]`:

   `//*[@id='project-update-success-information']/text()[normalize-space()]`

---

Note that, in general, there is no guarantee that the text content of an element will be in one single text node. It is very likely that you will sometimes encounter HTML or XML where elements have several text nodes, all of them containing non-whitespace characters, e.g.:

```
<div>
Project
<span/>
Updated
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but If I use that XPath that returns me text, so if I use driver.findElement, I will get error. is there any way to use that xpath....

Comment: @LokeshS I'm not very familiar with Selenium, so I do not really know if there is another method you can use. But yes, `findElement()` will not work if the XPath expression locates anything other than an element node ( a text node, in this case). Then why don't you go with the first solution, use an XPath expression that finds an element, use `findElement()` for this, use `getText()` on it and deal with the multiple results in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try this text() method like below:-

```
//span[@class='fa fa-check']/text()
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I tried that in firepath, for the first line, it has displayed text, but for the next one it doesn't displayed any text.

Comment: Which second line? Critical? ... Please update the HTML if you have any other line. It will help me to find out the problem

Comment: for the first one it has displayed the text in firepath, but for the second one it didn't displayed... one moment... i am updating my xpath and html....

Comment: Try this xpath ->   .//*[@id='project-update-success-information'][1]/text()

Answer (score 0):

The element is empty and thus contains no text

```
<span class="fa fa-check"/>
```

If on the other hand it was like

```
<span class="fa fa-check">Some content</span>
```

then it would, as in yor first attempt, contain some text.
Without knowing more of the content I would try another xpath method: following-sibling.

Comment: Following sibling means next node in the tree on the same "level".
Somthing like: //span[@class='fa fa-check']/following-sibling/text()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("panel-confirmation success")).getText();
```

Comment: I am using generic method in which i use xpath so, i can't use that

Comment: So try this- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='fa fa-check']").getText()